# Rock-paper-scissors game using sockets in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I would like to write a very simple rock-paper-scissors game in Python. I would like to have 1 server and 2 clients. After connecting to the server, the server should send a message to each client to choose (r/p/s). After this, each client should send back their choice and the server then decides about the winner, and then it informs the clients about the winner.

This is what I have so far:

This is the server.py

```
import socket
from threading import Thread

class ClientThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        print("[+] New server socket thread started for " + ip + ":" + str(port))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
            print("Server received data:", data)
            MESSAGE = input("Server response: ")
            if MESSAGE == 'exit':
                break
            conn.send(MESSAGE.encode())

TCP_IP = '0.0.0.0'
TCP_PORT = 2004
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

tcpServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpServer.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpServer.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
threads = []

while True:
    tcpServer.listen(4)
    print("Multithreaded Python server : Waiting for connections from TCP clients...")
    (conn, (ip, port)) = tcpServer.accept()
    newthread = ClientThread(ip, port)
    newthread.start()
    threads.append(newthread)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

This is clientA.py:

```
import socket

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 2004
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = input("tcpClientA:")

tcpClientA = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpClientA.connect((host, port))

while MESSAGE != 'exit':
    tcpClientA.send(MESSAGE.encode())
    data = tcpClientA.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
    print(" ClientA received data:", data)
    MESSAGE = input("tcpClientA:")

tcpClientA.close()
```

This is clientB.py:

```
import socket

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 2004
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = input("tcpClientB:")

tcpClientB = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpClientB.connect((host, port))

while MESSAGE != 'exit':
    tcpClientB.send(MESSAGE.encode())
    data = tcpClientB.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
    print(" ClientB received data:", data)
    MESSAGE = input("tcpClientB:")

tcpClientB.close()
```

In this code, however, I can only send messages to the server and it can respond. Unfortunately, I don't know, how I can send messages to a specific client in this case. (I need to send different messages to the winner and to the loser).

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not a trivial exercise and it will require a decent understanding of how threads work and how to work with them in Python in particular. What you seem to be missing at the moment is a way of orchestrating the communication from the 2 clients and of keeping track of what each client played so you can decide which client wins.

What currently happens is that when `tcpClientA.connect((host, port))` runs on client A, `(conn, (ip, port)) = tcpServer.accept()` gets unblocked in the server. This creates a new instance of your `ClientThread` class and the new thread starts listening for data to be sent by client A on the connection. When client B runs, the same happens and you now have 2 threads running and listening for data but no way of knowing which plays what.

What I would suggest is to introduce a new class that will represent the game itself. That class will get the messages from both client and respond to each accordingly. What you will also need is a way of waiting for both clients to have played their turn before being able to decide who wins and what to send to each.

One way to do it would be with [Barrier objects](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html#barrier-objects).